# How to Convert EBCDIC To HEX?

Tags: oracle11g

In this image EBCDIC value "I" we want To Hex format

[image]

In Oracle I am trying to convert "I" to "C9" but I don't know how to do. so please help me out.

Exa.
EBCDIC("I") -> HEX(C9)

Comment: No, in oracle I am trying to convert EBCDIC("I") to Hex "C9" through the oracle function. I know what is the value of "I" but we want code.

Comment: You have to convert it like convert( some_variable, 'US7ASCII', 'WE8EBCDIC500

Comment: I tried this way but it's returning "?"  "select convert('I', 'US7ASCII', 'WE8EBCDIC500')from dual;"

Comment: You have to know the correct encoding .WE8** is just an example

Comment: Now i tried  "select convert('É', 'US7ASCII', 'WE8EBCDIC500')from dual;" this and it's return "I" but I  want if I give "I" it should return "C9".

Comment: Please let me know correct encoding because I tried to use different different encoding but no luck.

Comment: The example I gave is convert to ASCII.. but since you want it to hex you have to use hex encoding instead of us7ascii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Fact for helping, I appreciate your support.

I used below query and it's working now Yaaaappppyyyyy.

select rawtohex(CONVERT(NVL("I", '0'), 'WE8EBCDIC500', 'US7ASCII')) from dual;

Result: C9